# EF 4.1 code first having issues in inserting parent and child objects

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Ef 4.1 code first.

I am getting the follwing error and not sure what I am doing wrong:

**An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.**

Inner exception:

**Invalid column name 'GrantApplicationIs'.
Invalid column name 'GrantApplication_Id'.**

I have a grant application and I am trying to add an audit entry to it when I save it to the database.

Here is my context:

```
public class HbfContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Bank> Banks { get; set; }
   public DbSet<AccountType> AccountTypes { get; set; }
   public DbSet<GrantApplication> GrantApplications { get; set; }
   public DbSet<AuditEntry> AuditEntries { get; set; }
}
```

Grant Application class:

```
public class GrantApplication
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<AuditEntry> AuditEntries { get; set; }
}
```

AuditEntry class:

```
public class AuditEntry
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int OldValue { get; set; }
   public int NewValue { get; set; }
   public DateTime AuditDate { get; set; }
   public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
   public int GrantApplicationIs { get; set; }
   public GrantApplication GrantApplication { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I add a new audit entry to a new grant application:

```
public void Insert(GrantApplication grantApplication)
{
   DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
   string submitterEmployeeNumber = "123456";

   grantApplication.SignatureDate = currentDateTime;
   grantApplication.SubmitterEmployeeNumber = submitterEmployeeNumber;

   // Add audit entry
   grantApplication.AuditEntries = new List<AuditEntry>();
   grantApplication.AuditEntries.Add(new AuditEntry
   {
      NewValue = grantApplication.GrantApplicationStateId,
      AuditDate = currentDateTime,
      EmployeeNumber = submitterEmployeeNumber
   });

   // Insert the new grant application
   grantApplicationRepository.Insert(grantApplication);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

My table structures looks like this:

`GrantApplications` table:

```
Id int
EmployeeNumber varchar(6)
Title varchar(10)
FirstName varchar(50)
LastName varchar(50)
```

`AuditEntries` table:

```
Id int
GrantApplicationId int
OldValue int
NewValue int
AuditDate datetime
EmployeeNumber varchar(6)
```

I have no idea what `GrantApplicationIs` and `GrantApplication_Id` and why they are column names.  From what?

Comment: Shouldn't this `GrantApplicationIs` be `GrantApplicationId` instead?

Comment: I have no idea what GrantApplicationIs is and where it comes from.  I don't even have a column with this name in my GrantApplication table.

Comment: @Brendan not in your table. but in your `AuditEntry` class you have a property `GrantApplicationIs`.

Comment: @Brendan: How did you get those entity classes?

Comment: @Ladislav: Sorry for all the trouble.  It was a typo from my side.  GrantApplicationIs is supposed to be GrantApplicationId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks that this is the source of the problem:

```
public int GrantApplicationIs { get; set; }
```

Is this a typo? Shoudn't it be `GrantApplicationId`? Anyway the effect is:

- `GrantApplicationIs` isn't recognized as the foreign key property for the `GrantApplication` navigation property. Instead it's an ordinary scalar property. If you don't have a column named like this in the DB you get your first exception: **Invalid column name 'GrantApplicationIs'**.
- EF uses the default name for the FK database column which is `GrantApplication_Id`. If you don't have a column named like this in the DB you get your second exception: **Invalid column name 'GrantApplication_Id'**.

Solution:

- Either name the FK property according to conventions (`GrantApplicationId`)
- Or apply data annotations or Fluent API to tell EF that `GrantApplicationIs` is indeed your FK property (and create an appropriate column in the DB).

Comment: @Brendan: Yes, I expected that your tables would look like this. The problem is that your property name `GrantApplicationIs` in your `AuditEntry` class doesn't match the column name `GrantApplicationId` in the DB. You said that you are using Code-First, so you have written your classes by hand, right? Can't you simply change the property name to `GrantApplicationId`? This would be the easiest way to fix both exceptions.

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble.  It was a typo from my side.  GrantApplicationIs is supposed to be GrantApplicationId.

Comment: Slauma - Is EF tolerant of variations on the FK field names in the database? For instance: GrantApplicationId  vs. GrantApplicationID  vs.  GrantApplication_Id  vs.  GrantApplication_ID  ?

Comment: @MattSlay: With or without underscore matters. Small or capital letters don't, I believe, depending on if the database system treats column names as case sensitive or not. In SQL Server for example they are not case sensitive.